# SQL Multiple Update Statements

Tags: php, sql

I need to update 40 rows in a database, starting at the point where the `userID` is a match. I do not want to have to determine the row number because eventually this database will be huge.

What I would like to do is simply say:

> "Update these the next 40 rows with my array where userID = myUserID"

Here is what I have:

```
<?php
// connect to the database and select the correct database
$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","Database","Password");
if (!$con2)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("ifaves_code", $con2);

$i = 0;
while ($i < 40) {

//cycle through the array
$cycleThrough2 = $updatedUserNames[$i];

//$query = "UPDATE tblUserLinks SET `URLName` = '$cycleThrough2' WHERE userID = '" . $mainUID . "' LIMIT 1";

mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
++$i;

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

The variable `$mainUID` is being set correctly, the problem I'm having is it appears there are no updates taking place in the database.

How can I alter my existing code to receive my desired behaviour?

Comment: When you say "next 40 rows" what do you mean? Next in what ordering?

Answer (score 3):

I don't suppose it's because you have your query building statement commented out...

```
//$query = "UPDATE tblUserLinks SET `URLName` = '$cycleThrough2' WHERE userID = '" . $mainUID . "' LIMIT 1";
```

If this is just the result of debugging and it wasn't working before that, you must call `mysql_error()` right after `mysql_query()` to see why it is failing.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
```

Also, you are using `LIMIT 1` at the end, but the `userID` never changes in the WHERE clause. Therefore, you are updating the same row over and over 40 times on each loop.  What you need is a way in your WHERE clause to identify rows which have already been modified, and exclude them.  Otherwise, the same row (first match) will always be caught by the `LIMIT 1` and updated.

Comment: ooops that was from a test even with it uncommented it does not work. Sorry about that haha.

Comment: @Mike see addition above about updating the same row over and over

Comment: Thank you Michael, I was hoping it would cycle through the rows where it found the first userID. I'll get the row number and cycle through that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @mMike: Do you mean you want the row with `userID = '$mainUID'` and the next 39 (bigger than `$mainUID`) userIDs?